# Re-enable and Disabling secure boot on dual boot WIN 11 and Kali?

Tags: kali-linux, dual-boot, uefi, secure-boot

So, I am basically a Linux user and just hop onto Windows whenever I want to play games or anything stupid. Most of my games now actually run when secure boot is enabled but as I am using Kali already as my main and working OS.

So, is it possible that I can enable secure boot and when I am done using Windows I restart disable the secure boot and run grub boot loader which is by default right now? Or will it cause errors? I don't know how to properly signed os right now.

Answer (score 0):

> So is it possible that i can enable secure boot and when i am done using windows i restart disable the secure boot and run grub boot loader which is by default right now?

Yes, it's perfectly possible but tedious. You could consider these other two options:

- You could use Fedora or Ubuntu whose Platform Keys are built-in in many motherboards which means you can run Linux with secure boot enabled. I've been running Fedora this way for many years now on my HP laptop.
- You can generate and employ your own EUFI Platform Keys, sign your Kali kernel and modules and again continue to run your system in secure boot mode. You'll have to sign the kernel and its modules for each new kernel update. As a bonus you'll be able to use third-party kernel modules this way (e.g. VirtualBox, VMWare, etc.) which is not possible with the first option. A con will be that a BIOS update could erase your platform keys and you'll need to add them to your BIOS again but BIOS updates are relatively rare.

More on it here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface/Secure_Boot#Using_your_own_keys

Comment: I know this, but I was wondering whether to enable secure boot and disabling it will work with the grub. Like, will enable it to affect the partition or something like that? or after enabling it will load windows and if I disable it, it will boot the bootloader automatically?

Comment: Secure Boot is a a mode of operation of your UEFI. It doesn't touch or alter your data. It just verifies the digital signatures of the files running in Ring-0 mode (kernel/drivers/modules) and if there's no valid signature, the files will not be executed.

Comment: But will it get executed after i disable it again?

Comment: What will get executed? Secure boot or not, **the same files are getting executed** for booting the system. Secure boot makes sure only verified kernel-level files are allowed to be executed.